# Using an ellipsis to show omission, when we skip complete sentences. 3 or 4 dots?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, typography, ellipses

Imagine I want to quote this text (the parts in bold):

> **If there were such a thing, I think I'd be a champion.** You know, baking under dangerous conditions, high-speed frosting... all hypothetical examples, obviously. **Of course assuming I don't live in a madhouse.**

Should I quote it with 4 dots, because I'm skipping a full sentence?

> If there were such a thing, I think I'd be a champion. . . . Of course assuming I don't live in a madhouse.