# How to Properly Cut Content and Show Content is Cut

Tags: ellipses, typography, paragraphs

I hope this is the proper place to ask this question:

I have a news article that I am citing for a post online. I am quoting part of the article but I am going to quote the first part of the article and then quote the very end. How do I properly show that the middle of the article is cut out?

IE:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum commodo purus. Vestibulum eget adipiscing mi. Morbi in consequat urna. Vestibulum imperdiet ullamcorper risus vitae vulputate.
>
> [Cut Content]
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum commodo purus. Vestibulum eget adipiscing mi. Morbi in consequat urna. Vestibulum imperdiet ullamcorper risus vitae vulputate.

I will provide a link back to the full article.

Comment: Also see  [Using an ellipsis to show omission, when we skip complete sentences. 3 or 4 dots?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105060), or [Space before three dots?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91653), or [What is the proper way of using triple dots and spaces before/after them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26240), or other [ellipsis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis?sort=active&pagesize=50) questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard indicator of missing content is `[...]`, for example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum commodo purus. Vestibulum eget adipiscing mi. Morbi in consequat urna. Vestibulum imperdiet ullamcorper risus vitae vulputate.
>
> [...]
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum commodo purus. Vestibulum eget adipiscing mi. Morbi in consequat urna. Vestibulum imperdiet ullamcorper risus vitae vulputate.

Comment: +1 But many style guides, such as the Modern Language Association, call for 4 dots [. . . . ]if the omission crosses sentences. See discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Comment: @bib thanks, I had no idea, I have only ever seen the one I suggested.

Comment: @bib - My omission is multiple sentences, thanks for the information.

Comment: @terdon It's one period for the end of the sentence and three more to indicate the ellipsis. When you use a sentence ellipse, you set the first dot against the text instead of adding a space before it. . . . Like that.